# Cloning 64TB HD to offsite replica

Tags: macos, hard-drive, backup, clone

I have a 64 TB Hard Drive currently only about halfway full in my home plugged into a mac mini. I have another 64 TB at my workplace also connected to a mac mini. I'd like to create a running clone of my home HD at my work for offsite backup purposes. I've looked into some backup solutions out there, but I haven't found any that allow you to actually clone drives. What would be the best way or system for me to use to create an automatic continuous clone at my workplace?

Comment: bittorrent sync? rsync?

Comment: I hope you've got a very fast connection, or are thinking about doing the first sync by taking one to the other & using at least 1000Base-T. I have a mere 2TB backed up offsite [not a clone just a file copy, on Backblaze so I don't think it's what you are asking for] however that took 3 months to complete the first full backup, on a 150/12 line.